# How to connect database with test complete tool

Tags: testcomplete, database-connection

I want to connect with my MySQL database with the help of test complete. I am able to connect with MySQL Work Bench but I never try with test complete tool.

Comment: While working with Microsoft ADO objects i am not able to define my connection string can any one please give me an example for this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a script in any language php, python, java ....etc. and call it with test complete 
for example to use python you can use  this code

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
cnx.close()
```

you find read more  here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

good luck!

Comment: i use java script for Test Complete automation

Comment: JavaScript can not directly connect to MySQL. But you can mix JS with PHP to do so.
JavaScript is a client-side language and your MySQL database is going to be running on a server.
OR you can use node.js ,but that's another  story ,see here for more details 
https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the corresponding OLE DB or ODBC Provider to work with your database from TestComplete. Find a suitable connection string [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) and then use one of the approaches to work with a DB described in the [Working With Databases](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56229/) help topic.

Please note that you may need to download and install [MySQL OLE DB or ODBC Provider](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) first.